# Size of a table in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have table calle users_session which I want it to hold only 8 rows. I am trying to implement my code so that if the number of rows is 8 the user is not added but if it is less the user is added. The problem is that it seems as if the code after the while loop not the one inside does not work.

Basically want I am trying to achieve is that is the user is already in the table he is let  in the game, if he is not and the table is full, a message is displayed saying it is full, and if the user is not in the table but it is not full he is added to the table.

Thank you, hope someone can help me!

```
<?php session_start();
$member_id = $_SESSION['member'];

// establishing connection to the database

require ('database_connection.php');

$my_database = mysql_select_db("roulette") or die("Database wasn't found!");

// counting the number of rows in the users_session table

$count_rows = "SELECT * FROM users_session";
$count_rows_query = mysql_query($count_rows) or die("<p> <font face=verdana> selecting rows failed!</p>");
$number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($count_rows_query) or die("<p> <font face=verdana> Counting rows failed!</p>");

// getting the contents of the table users_session

$query = "SELECT * FROM  users_session";
$select_query = mysql_query($query) or die("<p> <font face=verdana> Fetching rows failed!</p>");
$isAlready = false;

// fetch and check every row in the table

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select_query))
    {

    // if the user is already inside the session

    if ($member_id == $rows['member_id'])
        {
        $isAlready = true;
        print "<script> alert('You are already listed in the session') </script>";
        include ('one_number_bet.php');

        }
      else
        {
        $isAlready = false; //user is not in the session
        }
    }

print "test";
print $number_of_rows;

// if user is not in the session

if ($isAlready = true)
    {

    // checking if the table is full

    if ($number_of_rows < 8)
        {
        print "<script> alert('The session is full, please try again later') </script>";
        include ("type_of_bet.php");

        }

    // table is not full

      else
        {

        // add the user in the session

        $query = "INSERT INTO users_session (member_id) VALUES ('$member_id');";
        $insert_query = mysql_query($query) or die("<p> <font face=verdana> Insertion failed!</p>");
        print "<script> alert('You have been successfully added to the session') </script>";
        include ("one_number_bet.php");

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably missed the question? Also, why are you calling the same query twice?

Comment: there is an array property called num_rows you can use for this. they're going to tell you to stop using mysql_ functions and switch to mysqli or PDO. once you have your results you can call fetch_assoc on it, no need for a loop, then do a if($rows->num_rows < 9)

Comment: Sorry but I am not understanding because this is my first time using php and mysql, I am learning through the internet. The function you are saying isn't that the one I am using "mysql_num_rows($count_rows_query)" which returns the number of rows. But is I remove the loop wouldn't that be like just fetching the first row? Thanks for replying

Comment: What is `< ?` in `<?php < ? PHPsession_start();`? You should remove both symbols.

Comment: I arranged in it to <php? .... code .... ?> thanks

Answer (score 0):

To know the number of lines in a table, just execute this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM your_table
```

In PHP, you need to do:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM your_table");
$nb = mysql_result($res, 0);
```

Comment: Hi the problem in my code is where I have to check whether the user is already listed in the table or not. THe part where I got the number of rows is ok because I realised that the function mysql_num_rows returns a string and I change my code accordingly.

What I can't figure out is how to implement the different if statements to make sure that:

- if the user is in the table he is taken to another page
- if the user is not in the table and the table is full he is denied access
- if the table is not full and there is a user wanting access he is added to the table

Comment: In php that query does not work is return resource #5 which I do not know what it is

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code outside of the loop is not working is because your checking a variable that is never going to be anything but false when it is out of the loop. Inside the loop it turns true, but that true variable does not jump outside of the loop. Either put all of your IF statements into the While Loop or put the $isAlready variable into a $_SESSION variable to be used outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that should help you to identify active session and users.

Since i do not like posting untested code, and a will not use 'mysql_*' routines i have converted it to 'mysqli'.

Change the 'newActiveUser' variable to see the new results.

it is tested.

```
<?php

/*
 * return useful information about active users:
 *
 * 1) active_sessions_count => number of active 'admin' users
 * 2) known_user_was_found  => whether the username is is known
 * 3) active_user_was_found => where the supplied user name is active
 *
 */
// connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testmysql');

$newActiveUser = 'user9';

// makes the query easier to read and maintain - no other reason
$activeUsersSql = <<<'EOD'
SELECT COUNT(*) AS active_sessions_count,
       known_user_was_found,
       active_user_was_found

FROM user_session,

     (SELECT COUNT(users.username) AS known_user_was_found
      FROM users
      WHERE users.username = ?) AS known_user,

     (SELECT COUNT(user_session.username) AS active_user_was_found
      FROM user_session
      WHERE user_session.username = ?) AS active_user
EOD;
// end of query

$query = $db->prepare($activeUsersSql);

if  ($db->errno) {
    echo '<br/>prepare error: ', $db->errno, ' : ', $db->error, '<br/>';
}

// bind input params
$query->bind_param('ss', $newActiveUser, $newActiveUser);

if(!$query->execute()) {
    echo '', $db->errno, ' : ', $db->error, '<br/>';
}

// get the results
$results = $query->get_result();
if ($db->errno) {
    echo '<br/>results error: ', $db->errno, ' : ', $db->error, '<br/>';
}

$row =  $results->fetch_assoc();

// show results 
var_dump($row);
```

Sample data:

Known users:

```
username  name      
--------  ------    
user1     user1          
user2     user2      
user3     user3      
user4     user4   
user5     user5   
user6     user6   
user7     user7   
user8     user8   
user9     user9
```

Active sessions:

```
username  
----------
user1     
user2     
user3     
user4     
user5     
user6     
user7     
user8
```